# DynamoDB getItem returns empty item

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I am using the aws-sdk within Node and trying to get an item from a DynamoDB table but it prints just `Success {}` and not the actual content of the item. Does anyone know how to get the actual content of the item?

The Node script I am using is the following:

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'ap-southeast-2'});

// Create the DynamoDB service object
var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

var params = {
  TableName: 'test_table',
  Key: {
    'TWEET_KEY' : {S: 'Test'}
  },
  ProjectionExpression: 'ATTRIBUTE_NAME'
};

// Call DynamoDB to read the item from the table
ddb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", data.Item);
  }
});
```

and the actual data within the DynamoDB test_table which I'm trying to get is as follows:
[image]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here - `ProjectionExpression: 'ATTRIBUTE_NAME'`, you need to set the attribute names that you need to get,  or just remove it to get the whole record content.

Comment: Additionally, you can use `https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-data-types` to unwrap the returned data into normal json object.